# Test-Connection Performance Better with HostName

Tags: performance, powershell, ping

Running `Test-Connection` with an IP address takes considerably longer than running the same command with the server's hostname.

However; if I add the `-quiet` parameter then performance is roughly the same (IP is a fraction faster, as you may expect).

Using `Measure-Command` this anomaly does not show up; presumably some quirk of the output not being displayed.

The below code more accurately reflects the anomaly seen:

```
$begin=(get-date).ticks;test-connection '123.45.67.89'; $a=((get-date).ticks - $begin)
$begin=(get-date).ticks;test-connection 'MyHostName'; $b=((get-date).ticks - $begin)
$a-$b
```

Colleagues have reproduced the same issue on their machines.

**Question:** is anyone aware of what may cause this?
i.e. I suspect it's a bug (and have reported it as such), but it implies that there's something clever going on where PowerShell may work differently depending on whether output is to be displayed or not / causing a quantum-like effect; so it's not just running the commands given in order, but is doing some (de)optimisation under the covers.

**My Environment**

OS: MS Windows 7 Pro SP1

`$PSVersionInfo`:

```
Name                           Value                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      4.0                                     
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                 
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444                         
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406                          
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

**MS Connect Bug**

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1578010/test-connection-performance-with-ip-and-output

Comment: Word of advice: Don't use Get-Date to do forensic measurements like this. Use `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()`. I'm able to reproduce btw

Comment: This is guesswork (haven't done a network trace yet), but it might be that PowerShell tries to do a reverse lookup for the IP to resolve to a hostname in the `Destination` field of the output

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen; good shout; I'd wondered if that were the case before the ping occurred, but couldn't figure out why / how hiding output would affect it... if it only does that when outputting results though that makes more sense with what's seen.  Strange that they do that lookup on every iteration rather than caching it, but presumably there's a reason (perhaps in case DNS changes between pings)?

Comment: Found the culprit, will upload screenshots and further explanation later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a Wireshark trace while running `Test-Connection` with and without the `Quiet` switch parameter, supplying an IPv4 address for the `Computername` parameter.

When the `Quiet` switch is omitted, PowerShell seems to send not 1, but 6 NetBIOS Name Queries to the target machine, after which it returns the formatted output.

If I *assign* the output from `Test-Connection`, it returns right away, but as soon as I pipe it to `Format-Table`, it hangs and sends the NBSTAT queries again

---

The root cause is actually not the `Test-Connection` cmdlet itself, but the formatted output. One of the properties (`IPV4Address`) is a `ScriptProperty` and has the following definition:

```
PS C:\> $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.0.0.101 -Count 1
PS C:\> Get-Member -InputObject $ping -Name IPV4Address | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
System.Object IPV4Address {get=$iphost = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($this.address)
                    $iphost.AddressList | ?{ $_.AddressFamily -eq [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork } | select -first 1;}
```

So, when the output shown, `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry(10.0.0.101)` is called to calculate `IPV4Address` - this is what causes the waiting time

---

If you don't care about the moot resolution of the IP address, use `Select-Object` to prevent the calculation and output of `IPV4Address`:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName 10.0.0.101 -Count 1 | Select Address,StatusCode
```