# Invoke-Command on remote session returns local values

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-5.0, winrm, invoke-command

## Question

Should the script block of `Invoke-Command`, when run with a PSSession, always run on the remote computer?

## Context

I ran the below powershell against a list of servers:

```
Clear-Host
$cred = get-credential 'myDomain\myUsername'
$psSessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName @(1..10 | %{'myServer{0:00}' -f $_}) -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $psSessions -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Item -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters' 
} | Sort-Object PSComputerName
# $psSessions  | Remove-PSSession
```

This returned:

```
    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos


Name                           Property                   PSComputerName
----                           --------                   --------------
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer01
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer02
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer03
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer04
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer05
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer06
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer07
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer08
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer09
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
Parameters                     MaxPacketSize : 1          myServer10
                               MaxTokenSize  : 65535
```

All looks good; onlyl I'd not expected to see these values / I was running this as a quick sense check before setting the values on these servers to ensure I didn't overwrite anything.

I had a quick look at one of the servers using regedit; and found that `MaxTokenSize` and `MaxPacketSize` did not exist.

I then amended the command to use `Get-ItemProperty` instead of `Get-Item`:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $psSessions -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters' -Name 'MaxTokenSize'
} | Sort-Object PSComputerName
```

This time I got 10 errors:

```
Property MaxTokenSize does not exist at path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MaxTokenSize:String) [Get-ItemProperty], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
    + PSComputerName        : myServer01
# ... (and the same for the other 9 servers, with only PSComputerName changing)
```

Regarding where the values that were returned came from... they're from my local machine.  Amending my local registry entries and rerunning the original command showed all "servers" as having the new value.

I'm guessing this is a bug; but because I've not played with `PSSession`s much so far wanted to check here in case it's an issue with my understanding / usage of these commands, or if there are known gotchas to watch out for when using `PSSession`s.

Comment: Pipe it to fl * or ft * so it doesn't use the format file to display the registry keys.  The format file runs get-itemproperty locally to try to display the properties.

Comment: What @js2010 said - the `Registry` provider adds a set of dynamic properties that reference the absolute path to the provider item on the source computer - which the formatting layer in your local session then execute just-in-time for your console to format and render it, resulting in the screen buffer actually showing the values fetched from your local machine _after_ `Invoke-Command` has returned

Comment: Wow; thank-you - did not expect that (though have seen something similar before where the format provider does more than just format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570260/361842 - which Mathias answered then too).

Comment: @JohnLBevan: While the linked answer is conceptually related, the problems there stem from _ETS_ (extended type system) definitions, not _formatting_ definitions, as in the case at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it to fl * or ft * so it doesn't use the format file to display the registry keys. The format file runs get-itemproperty locally to try to display the properties.

From the bottom of $PSHOME\Registry.format.ps1xml for type Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey:

```
<ScriptBlock>
  $result = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.PSPath |
      Select * -Exclude PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PsProvider |
      Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()
  $result = $result.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($result.Length, 5000) )
  if($result.Length -eq 5000) { $result += "..." }
  $result
</ScriptBlock>
```

Comment: Good sleuthing; while the workarounds (`Format-List *` and `Format-Table *`) avoid the inapplicable display of _local_ data, they're limited in that you'll only see registry value _names_, not also data.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**:

- The **root cause is a *bug*** in the [formatting instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) for registry keys (as of Windows PowerShell 5.1.18362.125 and PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.2) leading to the unexpected mix of remote and local information - see [GitHub issue #10341](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10341).

  - As an aside: Similarly, PowerShell's [ETS (extended type system)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml) can introduce problems too, as shown in Mathias' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570260/45375).
- The best **workaround** is to simply use `Get-ItemProperty` (without a `-Name` argument) instead of `Get-Item`.

---

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question, and [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401778/45375) provides a limited workaround and a pointer to the root cause, but it's worth providing more background information:

PowerShell comes with [formatting instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) for type `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`, as output by `Get-Item` with a *registry* path.

These formatting instructions define a *calculated column* named `Property` for the default (tabular) view, which helpfully shows a summary of the output registry key's *values*, which involves accessing the registry *again*, using `Get-ItemProperty` as shown in js2010's answer.

However, that behind-the-scenes `Get-ItemProperty` call *always* accesses the *local* registry - even when the keys were retrieved *from a different machine*, via PowerShell remoting, so **you'll end up with a spurious mix of remote and local information**.

Note that, technically, when `Get-Item` is run *remotely*, what you receive *locally* is an *approximation* of the original `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` object, due to the serialization and deserialization involved in remoting. This approximation is a custom object with static copies of the original object's property values, and its (simulated) type name is `Deserialized.Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` - note the prefix.

PowerShell applies formatting instructions based on the *full type name* of output objects, but in the absence of a specific instructions or a given `Deserialized.<originalTypeName>` type, PowerShell applies the instructions for `<originalTypeName>`, which is what causes the problems here.

A - cumbersome, but edition-agnostic<sup>[1]</sup> - way to see the problematic formatting instruction is to run the following command:

```
(Get-FormatData Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey -PowerShellVersion $PSVersionTable.PSVersion).FormatViewDefinition.Control | % {
  $colNames = $_.Headers.Label
  $colValues = $_.Rows.Columns.DisplayEntry.Value
  foreach ($i in 0..($colNames.Count-1)) {
     [pscustomobject] @{
       ColumnName = $colNames[$i]
       ColumnValue = $colValues[$i]
     }
  }
} | Format-Table -Wrap
```

This yields the column names and definitions for the table view:

```
ColumnName ColumnValue                                                                                                                   
---------- -----------                                                                                                                   
Name       PSChildName                                                                                                                   
Property                                                                                                                                 
                $result = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.PSPath |                                        
                    Select * -Exclude PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PsProvider |                  
                    Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()                                                 
                $result = $result.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($result.Length, 5000) )                          
                if($result.Length -eq 5000) { $result += "..." }                                            
                $result
```

---

The workaround suggested in js2010's answer - piping to `Format-Table *` or `Format-List *` is effective in the sense that it prevents the inapplicable *local* information from being displayed: by specifying properties explicitly (even by wildcard pattern `*`), only *those* properties are displayed on output - not also the flawed calculated column.

However, while the true `Property` *property* of the output objects provides access to the value *names* in the registry key at hand, it doesn't provide the actual *data*, the way that the calculated `Property` *column* does.

By contrast, using `Get-ItemProperty` without a `-Name` argument in lieu of `Get-Item` as a workaround returns *both* value names and data (correctly even when remoting) and even does so without restrictions (whereas `Get-Item` limits output to 5000 chars.)

The output format will be slightly different, but all the information is there.

---

<sup>[1] That is, the command works also in PowerShell *Core*, where the built-in formatting instructions are no longer maintained as external `*.format.ps1xl` *files* and are instead compiled into the executable.</sup>